# Efficient way to get x Days, hours, and minutes from string and convert to dd:hh:mm

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, match

I have a string that can return as `1 days 15 hours 08 minutes` and I would like to convert it in the format of `dd:hh:mm`.

The string could also not have any days involved and look like `15 hours 08 mintues`.

My thought would be to grab all the groups of numbers with regex and check the count of what is returned. If there are 3 I know that I can assume there will be `dd:hh:mm`. If there are two, I would know that I have `hh:mm` etc...

Another option would be breaking up the string into potentially 3 strings... `"1 days", "15 hours", "08 minutes"` and then grabbing the numbers from that to build out the format I am looking for...

What would be the most efficient way of doing this with Javascript?

Comment: @charlietfl: months and years aren't necessary for what I am looking for. The longest time would be in days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach based on a regex which features [named capture groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) like the following one ...

[`/(?:\s*(?<days>\d+)\s*days*)?(?:\s*(?<hours>\d+)\s*hours*)?(?:\s*(?<minutes>\d+)\s*minutes*)?/`](https://regex101.com/r/HDrbb9/1/)

... combined with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#syntax) and a handy format helper functionality ...

```js
function formatDDHHMM(copy) {
  function doubleDigit(str) {
    return ((str.length === 1) && `0${ str }`) || str;
  }
  const {
    days,
    hours,
    minutes
  } = copy.match(
    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/HDrbb9/1]
    /(?:\s*(?<days>\d+)\s*days*)?(?:\s*(?<hours>\d+)\s*hours*)?(?:\s*(?<minutes>\d+)\s*minutes*)?/
  ).groups;

  return [
    doubleDigit(days || '00'),
    doubleDigit(hours || '00'),
    doubleDigit(minutes || '00'),
  ].join(':');
}

const sampleList = [
  '1 day 15hours 08 minutes',
  '1days 15 hour',
  '15 hours 08minute',
  '1 days 08 minutes',
  '08minutes',
  '15 hours',
  '1  day',
];

console.log(
  'sampleList.map(formatDDHHMM) ...',
  sampleList.map(formatDDHHMM)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think this is probably the most effective solution that should accommodate all possibilities. While I wish I had control of the data before it gets into this format, it is the best I can do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

match() the digit groups which returns an array, padStart() in map() to add leading zero when needed and join() with a colon delimiter.

Not sure what to do with 3 digit days or if it is probable.

Following assumes hours and minutes will always be included and days optional

```js
const input = ['1 days 15 hours 08 minutes', '15 hours 08 mintues', '22 days 1 hours 0 minutes'];

const timeFromString = (str) => {
  const digits = str.match(/\d+/g);
  if (digits.length === 2) {
    digits.unshift('00');
  }
  return digits.map(s => s.padStart(2, '0')).join(':')
}

input.forEach(s=> console.log(timeFromString(s)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient? That would be to get those numbers before they are concatenated into a String. Yet, I digress:

```js
function dhm(string){
  const s = string.match(/[0-9]+/g);
  let d = 0, h = 0, m = 0;
  switch(s.length){
    case 3:
      d = +s[0]; h = +s[1]; m = +s[2];
      break;
    case 2:
      d = +s[0]; h = +s[1];
      break;
    case 1:
      d = +s[0];
      break;
  }
  if(d < 10)d = '0'+d;
  if(h < 10)h = '0'+h;
  if(m < 10)m = '0'+m;
  return d+':'+h+':'+m;
}
const result = dhm('1 days 15 hours 08 minutes');
console.log(result);
```

Note that you format may confuse a Client, because it really looks like `hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: I agree about the days in a time format, seems strange

Comment: @charlietfl  it's strange but it's PO "I would like to convert it in the format of dd:hh:mm."

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```js
const dhm = (function()
  {
  const keys = [ 'days','hours','minutes' ]
  return (val) =>
    {
    let res    = ['00','00','00' ]
      , num    = ''
    val.split(' ').forEach((inVal,i)=>
      {
      if (i&1) // i is odd
        {
        let p = keys.indexOf(inVal)
        if (p > -1) res[p] = num.padStart(2, '0')
        }
      else num = inVal  // i is even
      })
    return res.join(':')  
    }
  })();

[ '1 days 15 hours 08 minutes'
, '15 hours 08 minutes'
, '3 days 6 minutes' ].forEach(el => console.log(el,'->',dhm(el)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0;}
```